How to launch app when app is terminated an phone idle?
I need to make an app that shows phone features on its own in a showroom. App will demonstrate about phone and phone will be usable with other apps installed. Whenever User quits the app and finished using phone, app would be launched again.
I tried it with background_service but it throws error when quits the app. Even example app gives the error for the plugin.
On the other hands, I assume that app can determine activity from outside the app by using system_accessbility It gets activities on phone and returns as stram. Fair enough for checking activity.
But, how to always run processes even the app is completely closed?
These kind of apps are used by technologhy stores.  Are these apps much platform specific than flutter can handle?
